# How to Hide Continue and Cancel button on Flutter Stepper

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I wanna hide Continue and Cancel Button on Stepper
And change to On Enter Text Filed for continuing the step.
Is it possible?
How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already used this code for hiding Continue and Cancel.

Firt declare variable hide as bool and the value is false

```
bool hide = false;
```

Then use controlsBuilder in the stapper.

For Flutter >2.6

```
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, ControlsDetails dtl){
           return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: dtl.onStepContinue,
                child: Text(hide == true ? '' : 'NEXT'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: dtl.onStepCancel,
                child: Text(hide == true ? '' :'CANCEL'),
              ),
            ],
          ); 
        },
```

And for flutter <= 2.5

```
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, { VoidCallback? onStepContinue, VoidCallback? onStepCancel }) {
         return Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             TextButton(
               onPressed: onStepContinue,
               child:  Text(hide == true ? '' : 'NEXT'),
             ),
             TextButton(
               onPressed: onStepCancel,
               child: Text(hide == true ? '' : 'CANCEL'),
             ),
           ],
         );
      },
```

CMIIW

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Add This In Your Stepper:

```
        child: Stepper(
          controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
              ],
            );
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to hide stepper buttons:

```dart
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
},
```

You must past this piece of code inside `Stepper`

Answer (score 0):

```
      class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

       @override
        _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
       }

      class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
             int _currentstep = 0;

      
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    title: const Text('App',style: TextStyle(color: 
         Colors.white), ),
            ),
   

         body: Stepper(
          steps: [
    const Step(  state: _ _currentstep <= 0 ? 
      StepState.editing : StepState.complete,
      isActive: _ _currentstep >= 0,
         title: Text('Account'), content: Center(child: 
      Text('Account'),)),
     const Step(state: _ _currentstep <= 1 ? 
      StepState.editing : StepState.complete,
      isActive: _ _currentstep >= 1,title: Text('Address'), 
   content: Center(child: 
    Text('Address'),)),
      const Step(state: _ _currentstep <= 2 ? 
      StepState.editing : StepState.complete,
      isActive: _ _currentstep >= 2,title: Text('Confirm'), content: Center(child: 
      Text('Confirm'),))
           ],
      onStepContinue: () {
        if (_currentstep < (2)) {
          setState(() {
            _currentstep += 1;
          });
        } ),
        controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: _currentstep != 0
              ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
              : MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            if (_currentstep != 0)
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: 
       BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      fixedSize: Size(20.w, 6.h),
                      elevation: 0,
                      primary: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                  )),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    fixedSize: Size(45, 6),
                    primary: buttonColor),
                onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                child: Text(
                  "Next",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ))
          ],
        );
      },
          )
         );
          }
     }
```

by applying condition in controls builder you can hide or show the next or previous. button